# Fill null values with next incrementing number | PySpark | Python

Tags: python, postgresql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having below dataframe with values. I want to add next concecative id in the column id which must be unique as well incrementing in nature.

```
+----------------+----+--------------------+
|local_student_id|  id|        last_updated|
+----------------+----+--------------------+
|          610931|null|                null|
|          599768|   3|2020-02-26 15:47:...|
|          633719|null|                null|
|          612949|   2|2020-02-26 15:47:...|
|          591819|   1|2020-02-26 15:47:...|
|          595539|   4|2020-02-26 15:47:...|
|          423287|null|                null|
|          641322|   5|2020-02-26 15:47:...|
+----------------+----+--------------------+
```

I want below expected output. can anybody hemp me? I am new to Pyspark. and also want to add current timestamp in last_updated column.

```
+----------------+----+--------------------+
|local_student_id|  id|        last_updated|
+----------------+----+--------------------+
|          610931|   6|2020-02-26 16:00:...|
|          599768|   3|2020-02-26 15:47:...|
|          633719|   7|2020-02-26 16:00:...|
|          612949|   2|2020-02-26 15:47:...|
|          591819|   1|2020-02-26 15:47:...|
|          595539|   4|2020-02-26 15:47:...|
|          423287|   8|2020-02-26 16:00:...|
|          641322|   5|2020-02-26 15:47:...|
+----------------+----+--------------------+
```

actually i tried

```
final_data = final_data.withColumn(
        'id', when(col('id').isNull(), row_number() + max(col('id'))).otherwise(col('id')))
```

but it gives the below Error:-

```
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence is empty, and '`local_student_id`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(CASE WHEN (`id` IS NULL) THEN (CAST(row_number() AS BIGINT) + max(`id`)) ELSE `id` END AS `id`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap '`local_student_id`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the code you need :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

max_id = final_data.groupBy().max("id").collect()[0][0]

final_data.withColumn(
    "id",
    F.coalesce(
        F.col("id"),
        F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("id")) + F.lit(max_id)
    )
).withColumn(
    "last_updated",
    F.coalesce(
        F.col("last_updated"),
        F.current_timestamp()
    )
)
```